# How to select / change object from another composer scene in Corona SDK Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk, scene

**Scene A:** (creating global object)

```
someLine = display.newLine( 0,100, screenW,100 )
someLine:setStrokeColor( 0, 0, 0 )
```

**Scene B:** (changing public object)

```
someLine:setStrokeColor( 1, 1, 1 )
```

Changing object from scene A in scene B like in example above, does not work.
Any idea how to get to that object without some weird workarounds?

Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was using Globals in scene:Create, that's why that change in the example didn't work. By moving the change command to scene:Show it started working.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your values from one scenes to using ,

```
 -- Set the Composer variable "money" to 100
 composer.setVariable( "money", 100 )

 -- In another scene...
local currentMoney = composer.getVariable( "money" )
```

But never ever use global values.